# SAPUI5 Metadata.xml : binding two entities

Tags: javascript, json, xml, metadata, sapui5

I am in internship in a firm where I have to code in JS using SAPUI5 framework. It's totally new for me, that's why I followed the tutorial at http://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com . But now I have a problem, I can't find any advise on the Internet, and I can't always ask my colleagues to help me, they have a job too...

I have to do a planning with many employees and their task. I work with a mockserver with a metadata.xml file :

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
    <Schema xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="NorthwindModel">
        <EntityType Name="Employee">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="EmployeeID" />
            </Key>
            <Property xmlns:p8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
                Name="EmployeeID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"
                p8:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
            <Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"
                MaxLength="20" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
            <Property Name="City" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="Team" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
            <NavigationProperty Name="Appointments" Relationship="NorthwindModel.FK_Employees_Appointment"
                FromRole="Employees" ToRole="Appointments"/>
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Appointment">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="AppointmentID"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="AppointmentID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="EmployeeID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="start" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="end" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="title" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
            <NavigationProperty Name="Employees" Relationship="NorthwindModel.FK_Employees_Appointment"
                ToRole="Employees" FromRole="Appointments"/>
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="FK_Employees_Appointment">
            <End Type="Employee" Role="Employees" Multiplicity="1" />
            <End Type="Appointment" Role="Appointments" Multiplicity="*" />
            <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Employees">
                    <PropertyRef Name="EmployeeID" />
                </Principal>
                <Principal Role="Appointments">
                    <PropertyRef Name="EmployeeID" />
                </Principal>
            </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
    </Schema>
    <Schema xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="ODataWeb.Northwind.Model">
        <EntityContainer
            xmlns:p7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
            Name="NorthwindEntities" p7:LazyLoadingEnabled="true"
            m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
            <EntitySet Name="Employees" EntityType="NorthwindModel.Employee" />
            <EntitySet Name="Appointments" EntityType="NorthwindModel.Appointment"/>
            <AssociationSet Name="FK_Employees_Appointments" Association="NorthwindModel.FK_Employees_Appointment">
                <End Role="Employees" EntitySet="Employees"/>
                <End Role="Appointments" EntitySet="Appointments"/>
            </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
```

(for tags AssociationSet and NavigationProperty, I did it because I've seen on the OData service I use, but I don't understand it; I guessed it will be fine...)

Now the Appointments.json file :

```
[
{
    "AppointmentID" : 0,
    "EmployeeID" : 0,
    "start":"\/Date(1466416800000)\/",
    "end":"\/Date(1466424000000)\/",
    "title": "test"
},{
    "AppointmentID" : 1,
    "EmployeeID" : 1,
    "start":"\/Date(1466409600000)\/",
    "end":"\/Date(1466416800000)\/",
    "title": "test2"
}]
```

The Employees.json file :

```
[
{
    "EmployeeID":0,
    "LastName":"APERCE",
    "City":"Paris",
    "Team":"Dev"
},
{
    "EmployeeID":1,
    "LastName":"HACHMI",
    "City":"Lille",
    "Team":"Dev"
},
{
    "EmployeeID":2,
    "LastName":"MILLET",
    "City":"Paris",
    "Team":"Admin"
},
{
    "EmployeeID":3,
    "LastName":"CORNET",
    "City":"Poitiers",
    "Team":"Admin"
},
{
    "EmployeeID":4,
    "LastName":"EVAIN",
    "City":"Paris",
    "Team":"R&D"
}]
```

(As you can see, the EmployeeID is present on both Appointments.json et Employees.json)

And finally the Overview.view.xml file :

```
<mvc:View controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.Overview"
xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic"
xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" displayBlock="true">
<semantic:FullscreenPage title="{i18n>overviewPageTitle}">
    <VBox>
        <PlanningCalendar startDate="{path : '/Startdate'}" rows="{path : 'data>/Employees',parameters:{expand:'Appointments'}}"
            appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect">
            <rows>
                <PlanningCalendarRow title="{data>LastName}"
                    appointments="{path : 'data>Appointments',templateShareable:true}">
                    <appointments>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                            startDate="{data>start}"
                            endDate="{data>end}"
                            title="{data>title}">

                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </appointments>
                </PlanningCalendarRow>
            </rows>
        </PlanningCalendar>
    </VBox>
</semantic:FullscreenPage>
```

(the "data" model binds already with the metadata.xml and gets both Appointments.json and Employees.json)

Actually, this code displays the two tasks from Appointments.json for every employee in my planning. I want to bind it in order to have the appointment "test" only for the employee "APERCE" and "test2" only for "HACHMI", but I can't.

I believe it is possible to do something equivalent to a JOIN for a SQL Database, but I don't find anything about it. How should I do it ? Thank you for your answers.

PS : I am french, if you don't understand what I wrote above, sorry ; and if you can answer in french, do so, it will be better for my understanding.

**EDIT :** I have corrected the code according to nistv4n's advises. Now I get the following errors :

MockServer: Resource not found for the segment 'Appointment' => I understand that, the segment 'Appointment' doesn't exist since it's 'Appointment**s**', but I don't know where I forgot the 's'.

The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed404,Not Found,{"error":{"code":404,"message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource not found for the segment 'Appointment'"}}} => I guess it's related to the previous error, because it requests for 'Appointment' instead of 'Appointment**s**' ?

**REEDIT :** I put the 's' on the right places. Now I just have : Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined => because there is a problem with the model used in Overview.view.xml, probably in the , but it's the same if I use : "{Appointments/start}", "{Appointments>start}", "{start}" or "{/Appointments>start}".

**LASTEDIT :** Thanks to nistv4n, I finally did it. I have updated my code above if you have the same problem. The correct code is in PlanningCalendarRow => *appointments="{path : 'data>Appointments'}"* and in unified:CalendarAppointment => *startDate="{data>start}"* etc...

Actually, to quote nistv4n : "Appointments has a relative reference, and inner properties (start, end, title) has also a relative reference, including the model name."

Comment: what about startDate="{data>start}", endDate="{data>end}", title="{data>title}".

Comment: Every employee has the tasks "test" and "test2". But I want "test" only for "APERCE" and "test2" only for "HACHMI", and nothing for the others employees.

Comment: @Ash actually you were right, the problem was in the PlanningCalendarRow. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you define the binding for aggregation rows of `PlanningCalendar`, include the `$expand` keyword to make the referenced activities accessible in the container:

```
<PlanningCalendar startDate="{path : '/Startdate'}" rows="{path : 'data>/Employees', parameters:{expand:'Appointment'}}" 
appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect">
```

It will fetch the assigned `Appointment` data for the given employee. You can refer to that using the `Appointment/start` binding path inside the aggregation.

**Edit:** 
It seems you missed the Association node from the first schema. Define it like this:

```
<Association Name="FK_Employees_Appointment">
    <End Type="Employee" Role="Employees" Multiplicity="1" />
    <End Type="Appointment" Role="Appointments" Multiplicity="*" />
    <ReferentialConstraint>
        <Principal Role="Employees">
            <PropertyRef Name="EmployeeID" />
        </Principal>
        <Principal Role="Appointments">
            <PropertyRef Name="EmployeeID" />
        </Principal>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

I would recommend to define only one-way connection between the two entities.

Could you post your code to somewhere (even in a zip archive) to investigate the whole architecture and codeline?

Edit 2: Please change the `PlanningCalendarRow` segment of your View XML according to this:

```
<PlanningCalendarRow title="{data>LastName}"
    appointments="{path : 'data>Appointments',templateShareable:true}">
    <appointments>
        <unified:CalendarAppointment
            startDate="{data>start}"
            endDate="{data>end}"
            title="{data>title}">

        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
    </appointments>
</PlanningCalendarRow>
```

`Appointments` has a relative reference, and inner properties (`start`, `end`, `title`) has also a relative reference, including the model name.

Comment: Ok just it is Appointments with an 's', otherwise It doesn't recognize that. Now I have the following errors : 1) MockServer: Resource not found for the segment 'Appointments' |||| 2) The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed404,Not Found,{"error":{"code":404,"message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource not found for the segment 'Appointments'"}}}
I guess I missed something in metadata.xml like an <Association> tag in the first <Schema>. <br/> My colleague told me to read the doc at odata.org, I will look this side but it's about 350 pages.

Comment: And if I write Appointment w/o an 's' I get this error :  
The following problem occurred: HTTP request failedundefined,undefined,HTTP/1.1 NaN
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
dataserviceversion: 2.0

Comment: @NicolasApercé I just realized that I left some old code in the Association definition - the `End Type=""` part should be aligned to your schema, I updated my answer. I also want to see the whole project as a ZIP or JSBin because it's really hard to debug mock server on the fly.

Comment: How can I send it to you as a ZIP ? I don't know how to use JSBin

Comment: @NicolasApercé Just download the project if you are using WebIDE, or export it from Eclipse, or zip the whole folder. After that, you can upload it to the internet to make it downloadable.

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't clear, my question was : how to upload it to make it downloadable ? But I answered myself : here is a Mega link to my project : https://mega.nz/#!thZF0JAS!CzpLj7Vk4YYGgWW1uaWJZ6Gvfia7vF1qpIkVfdEjHNo

Comment: @NicolasApercé Thanks, I updated my answer. Now it's working at my side.